# How to return a filtered result of embedded documents through a query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for a query that can return only certain document inside an array that is embedded inside another array of a main document.
Below is the collection stored in DB:

```
{
    "List": {
        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35c",
        "capitalAccountID": "CaptialAccount-43",
        "userEmail": "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
        "flagID": 1,
        "ledgerName": "Capital Account",
        "subLedgers": [
            {
                "openingBalance": 100000,
                "closingBalance": 90001,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35e",
                        "transactionID": "123456",
                        "date": "09/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 0,
                        "debit": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35f",
                        "transactionID": "123457",
                        "date": "10/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d360",
                        "transactionID": "123458",
                        "date": "11/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35d",
                "subLedgerID": 1,
                "subLedgerName": "ABC",
                "reference": "dghj",
                "rateOfDuty": 10,
                "gstApplicable": true
            },
            {
                "openingBalance": 100000,
                "closingBalance": 95001,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d362",
                        "transactionID": "123459",
                        "date": "13/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 0,
                        "debit": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d363",
                        "transactionID": "123450",
                        "date": "14/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d364",
                        "transactionID": "123451",
                        "date": "15/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d365",
                        "transactionID": "123452",
                        "date": "16/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 0,
                        "debit": 5000
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d361",
                "subLedgerID": 2,
                "subLedgerName": "DEF",
                "reference": "dohj",
                "rateOfDuty": 10,
                "gstApplicable": true
            }
        ],
        "idCounter": 43,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

The code Below returns above result:

```
await CaptialAccount.findOne(
    {
      userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
    },
    (err, list) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        List: list
      })
    }
  );
```

I need to filter the "transactions" array inside "subLedgers" array based on date.
For example: From "09/06/2020" to "13/06/2020".
Expected Output:

```
{
    "List": {
        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35c",
        "capitalAccountID": "CaptialAccount-43",
        "userEmail": "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
        "flagID": 1,
        "ledgerName": "Capital Account",
        "subLedgers": [
            {
                "openingBalance": 100000,
                "closingBalance": 90001,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35e",
                        "transactionID": "123456",
                        "date": "09/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 0,
                        "debit": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35f",
                        "transactionID": "123457",
                        "date": "10/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d360",
                        "transactionID": "123458",
                        "date": "11/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 5000,
                        "debit": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d35d",
                "subLedgerID": 1,
                "subLedgerName": "ABC",
                "reference": "dghj",
                "rateOfDuty": 10,
                "gstApplicable": true
            },
            {
                "openingBalance": 100000,
                "closingBalance": 95001,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d362",
                        "transactionID": "123459",
                        "date": "13/06/2020",
                        "particulars": "By-sales",
                        "voucherNumber": "asdfghjk",
                        "voucherType": "SR",
                        "credit": 0,
                        "debit": 1
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5ee1c1e6739bb23e3c54d361",
                "subLedgerID": 2,
                "subLedgerName": "DEF",
                "reference": "dohj",
                "rateOfDuty": 10,
                "gstApplicable": true
            }
        ],
        "idCounter": 43,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Is there an query to achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a pipeline for this, utilizing [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). the query equivalent of [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) can be used only to return the first item in the array that matches the condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "List.subLedgers": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$List.subLedgers",
                    as: "subLedger",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: ["$$subLedger", {
                            transactions: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$$subLedger.transactions",
                                    as: "transaction",
                                    cond: {
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $gte: ["$$transaction.date", "start date"]
                                            },

                                            {
                                                $lte: ["$$transaction.date", "end date"]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

From what it looks like your transaction dates are saved as string, while this is not recommended it's fine as long as you can guarantee that they are all in the same timezone and format otherwise you're going to get unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you so much. This thing save half of my work. It will be great  if you provide a link where I could look for deep understanding of this code.

Comment: You can check Mongo's reference for all the available aggregation operators used here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/. apart from that if you want to understand anything specific better i'll be glad to answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.